# initializing 'CGFloat *' (aka 'float *') with an expression of type 'const CGFloat *' (aka 'const float *') discards qualifiers)

Tags: ios

when I try to get the components of `CGColor` with following code:

```
CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(customizedCGColor);
```

I get the warning of

> initializing 'CGFloat *' (aka 'float *') with an expression of type 'const CGFloat *' (aka 'const float *') discards qualifiers).

What is this and what does `CGFloat *` actually mean in detail, why not just using CGFloat.

Answer (score 1):

Colours are defined in terms of their red, green, blue and alpha intensities and that method is returning an array of those components; thus:

```
const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(customizedCGColor);
CGFloat red = components[0];
CGFloat blue = components[1];
CGFloat green = components[2];
CGFloat alpha = components[3];
```

However the number of components returned does depend on the colour space being used.

The reason you got the error is that the variable you used to hold the returned array was not `const`, and therefore an incorrect type.

The reason it is defined `const` is because the method does not want callers to change the colour components via the array it returns; for example if you try:

```
const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(customizedCGColor);
components[0] = newRed;
```

The compiler will generate an error as you cannot modify a `const` array.

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe! your answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign `const CGFloat` to `CGFloat` that is why you are getting that warning.

Define `const` for your `CGFloat` variable

```
const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(customizedCGColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update you declaration as follows:

```
CGFloat const *components = CGColorGetComponents(customizedCGColor);
```